# Slow nfs share on Windows 11 client

Tags: windows, network-interface, nfs

I’m having some trouble with an NFS share I have running on Rocky Linux 9.
I want to access it from a Windows 11 machine, both from the local network and from WAN.

I have it set up and working, but it’s really slow for example when opening a Word-document from the client.

I’ve tried from both WiFi, Ethernet and through Wireguard VPN on the client with the same result. I’ve also tried two different routers, TP-Link AX3000 and ASUS RT-AC68-U.
It gets a little better when I disable the firewall on the server, but it’s nowhere near acceptable performance.

This leads me to believe that I have several problems, one being the firewall, the other unknown. Could it be the ethernet driver causing problems on the server? I have the Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 controller.

Output of `nfsstat -r`:

```
Server rpc stats:
calls      badcalls   badfmt     badauth    badclnt
19892      368        368        0          0
```

Any input on this matter would be much appreciated, and if you need more info just let me know.

Comment: The question is if access to the NFS area is also slow from Linux client. If access from Linux client is ok, then it seems the issue is on the Windows side, in which case this question should probably be submitted to another SE site.

Comment: Also, start with simple tests; Instead of opening a Word document (which has a lot of internal dependencies and possible bottlenecks in the Word application itself), begin by trying to copy a file from the NFS share to the local disk, check the performance of this simple operation.

Comment: @aviro It also takes a while when I open explorer before I can see the disks mounted. I tried copying some image files getting about 10MB/s. Should be higher right? I have WiFi6 and 1000Gbit connection.
EDIT: I got an old laptop with linux on it which I will try to mount from.

Comment: Tried on a linux client, getting delays as well, and about 5.3MB/s copying the same folder. This is using nfsv3, since Windows don't have v4. nfsv4 is snappier though.
Could it have something to do with rpc?
EDIT: The lower speed is because of WiFi limits.